# Process file (which sit on Server A) on Server B

Tags: java, spring-boot

Since Server A and server B doesn't have SFTP, and I am try to implement a web service on Server B, that takes the file on Server A and process it. I tried using Spring boot to do this, like save the file first, and the process. But this way it seems like async, which means when the code try to process the file, the file is not ready yet, (confirm when I print the file location, it return null). What is the good way to handle this?

Current Code I have for the controller is following:

```
package com.example.filedemo.controller;

import com.example.filedemo.payload.UploadFileResponse;
import com.example.filedemo.service.FileStorageService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
public class FileController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);
    private static final String PYTHON_FILE = "V:/speechRecognition/audio_transcribe.py";
    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri =
            ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/downloadFile/").path(fileName).toUriString();

        return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }

    @PostMapping("/processFile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> processFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String filename = uploadFile(file).getFileName();
        File actualFile = new File("E:\\Audio\\uploads\\" + filename);
        String fetching = "python " + PYTHON_FILE + " " + actualFile.getAbsolutePath();
        String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", fetching};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        String pythonPath = System.getProperty("PYTHON_PATH");
        System.out.println("pythonPath is " + pythonPath);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String ret = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(ret);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }



}
```

`FileStorageService.java`

```
package com.example.filedemo.service;

import com.example.filedemo.exception.FileStorageException;
import com.example.filedemo.exception.MyFileNotFoundException;
import com.example.filedemo.property.FileStorageProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

@Service
public class FileStorageService {

    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileStorageService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
        this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir())
                .toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
        }
    }

    public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
            if(fileName.contains("..")) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
            }

            // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
            Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
            long numberOfByte = Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("Copy byte " + numberOfByte);
            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }

    public Resource loadFileAsResource(String fileName) {
        try {
            Path filePath = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName).normalize();
            Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
            if(resource.exists()) {
                return resource;
            } else {
                throw new MyFileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new MyFileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

`UploadFileResponse`

```
package com.example.filedemo.payload;


public class UploadFileResponse {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileDownloadUri;
    private String fileType;
    private long size;

    public UploadFileResponse(String fileName, String fileDownloadUri, String fileType, long size) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileDownloadUri = fileDownloadUri;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileDownloadUri() {
        return fileDownloadUri;
    }

    public void setFileDownloadUri(String fileDownloadUri) {
        this.fileDownloadUri = fileDownloadUri;
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with your code about what you tried yourself already otherwise this will just get downvotes and no answer

Comment: updated the code for controller

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the file in the database, then operating on it from there.  Obviously, be careful the file size doesn't overrun the column size.

If your operations require an actual file on disk (rather than, say, a stream of bytes), then you could create a sync service that polls the database for new files and saves a copy on the local disk when found.  Then your processing code can use the local disk file handle.

Comment: another way which is not save to DB? because server A may not access to DB.

Comment: Is the upload taking place on server A?  Or is server A simply the source of the files, and server B needs to copy them and process them?  Could the files be placed on a shared drive that B mounts so the files appear to be local?

Comment: Yes, the server A contains source file, and server B somehow need to get that file and process it. For shared drive I try but failing due to access denied

Comment: How is the file getting from Server A to B?  Are you uploading it to B via the /uploadFile endpoint from server A?  Or are you downloading it from A to your desktop, then uploading to B?  If you are downloading it from A to your desktop, what method are you using to download?  SFTP?  SCP?  HTTP?

Comment: The file will be generated in server A, once the file got generated, it will pass to server B to process it. And yes I thought calling ```/processFile``` on server A will do all the stuff, but it looks like not that case. Meanwhile I don't know can we using SFTP or not

Comment: Have you confirmed that /uploadFile works as you expect?  I don't think the call to uploadFile() from processFile() is asynchronous, but without the source to UploadFileResponse and FileStorageService, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204008/discussion-between-vincent-zheng-and-justin-guerin).